# C# List Tuple Coding exercise

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I'm a new to Tuple objects. I'm facing a C# tuple coding exercise and have no idea how to do it. Could someone leave me some suggestion or idea that I could use as a starting point for the exercises? Being honest, I don't even know how to start it. The questions is similar to below:

- There will be a `List< Tuple<int,int> >` variable which has `[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]` inside.
- Because the int `2` is present in *both* the 1st tuple element and 2nd tuple element, it will auto group the first tuple element and second tuple element together, *merging* them into one list.
- The target is to return 2 list variables:

  - `[1,2,3]` in the first list
  - `[4,5]` in the second list.
- The list is output from largest to smallest list size, but if the list sizes are equal, order by the first list's element from smaller int to larger int.

Example:

```
Input: [[0,1],[0,5],[2,3],[3,4],[4,6]]
Output:
    1st list: [2,3,4,6]
    2nd list: [0,1,5]
```

Could someone give me an idea of how to get started?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by this: "Because the int 2 is in the 1st tuple element and 2nd tuple element, it will auto group the first tuple element and second tuple element together and merge them into one list.". What do you mean by "auto-group"?

Comment: Hello Dai, thanks for taking time for looking of this question. As you could see in example, input list has 3 objects and each object has 2 elements. 1st object has element value int 1 and int 2, and the second object has element value int 2 and int 3. So it would need to out put a list which contains all element from 1st object and 2nd object with non-duplicate that was [1,2,3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example that should do it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Tuple<int, int>> input = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    input.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(0, 1));
    input.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(0, 5));
    input.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(2, 3));
    input.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(3, 4));
    input.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(4, 6));

    List<int> current = new List<int>();
    List<List<int>> output = new List<List<int>>();
    foreach(Tuple<int, int> T in input)
    {
        if (current.Count == 0 || current.Contains(T.Item1) || current.Contains(T.Item2))
        {
            current.Add(T.Item1);
            current.Add(T.Item2);
        }
        else
        {
            current.Sort();
            output.Add(current.Distinct().ToList());
            current = new List<int>();
            current.Add(T.Item1);
            current.Add(T.Item2);
        }
    }
    if (current.Count > 0)
    {
        current.Sort();
        output.Add(current.Distinct().ToList());
    }

    foreach(List<int> set in output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{String.Join(",", set)}]");
    }
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the suggestion for this task. This give me an idea of how to do this test. Thanks again Buddy!